# VerticalGridView smoothScrollBy scrolls back once the focus leaves grid item

Tags: android, leanback

I have a VerticalGridView which is extracted from RowsSupportFragment of leanback. The VerticalGridView needs to scroll in few cases, for which I am using smoothScrollBy(). The scroll works but VerticalGridView doesn't stay in that state. Once the focus leaves the grid item it scrolls back to its previous state. I have tried using scrollTo and scrollBy as well but that leads to different problems. Is there a way where the gridview can remain in scrolled position?

Comment: I have such issue.